# How can I create multiple action delegates at run time and add it in the list of action delegate?

Tags: list, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, delegates

My code is like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> specialCharacters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            specialCharacters.Add("@", "%");
            specialCharacters.Add("*", "^");

List<Action<Employee>> listOfDel = new List<Action<Employee>>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> character in specialCharacters)

{

Action<Employee> replace = (empData) => empData.EmpName =          empData.EmpName.ToString().Replace(character.Key, character.Value);

listOfDel.Add(replace);

//listOfDel.Add(new Action<Employee>((empData) => empData.EmpName = empData.EmpName.ToString().Replace(character.Key, character.Value)));

}
```

The issue is the list listOfDel has the same action as it refers to same function replace which takes value of last pair of character.Key, character.Value (("*", "^")
I want a result having different actions in the list of actions listOfDel  , where each method will have different value present.  ("@", "%"), ("*", "^");
I also tried creating a new instance of action delegate and using it as anonymous method.Please see commented code, yet the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're capturing the iterator variable. There's only *one* variable declared by the `foreach` loop, so by the time you *execute* the delegates, they'll all be using the same value (they all refer to the same delegate). For C# 4 and earlier, you just need to create a copy:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> character in specialCharacters)  
{
    var copy = character;
    Action<Employee> replace = empData => empData.EmpName =    
         empData.EmpName.ToString().Replace(copy.Key, copy.Value);

    listOfDel.Add(replace);    
}
```

C# 5 will render this unnecessary, as `foreach` will be fixed so that each iteration will have a separate variable as far as anonymous functions are concerned.

See Eric Lippert's blog post ["Closing over the loop variable considered harmful"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Resharper normally will warn us this about this, encouraging us to copy the variable of the loop to a local variable.